# Problemas con suma

Tags: sum

Estoy intentando aplicar el siguiente código para ordenar cantidad de horas por Mutualista, pero me tira un error.

¿Alguna idea a qué puede corresponder? Les dejo el código y el error a continuación. Gracias

> **Código:**
>
> ```
> DIASxMutualista = Servicios[(Servicios.Mutualista)].groupby('CantHoras').sum()
> DIASxMutualista = pd.DataFrame(DIASxMutualista)
> DIASxMutualista
> ```

> **Error:**

> ```
> None of [Index(['A', '', 'A', 'A',\n 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',\n 'A', 'A',\n ...\n 'B', 'B', 'B',\n 'B', 'B', 'B',\n 'B', 'B', 'B',\n 'B'],\n dtype='object', length=4685)] are in the [columns]
> ```

Comment: ¿Podrias identificar el lenguaje?¿ es python, sql,...?

Comment: Es en Python. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que tu problema no es de la funcion sum(), sino de los espacios y salto de linea "\n" en los nombres de las columnas, tu problema se parece mucho a este.... mirate la solcuion si no te da error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652574/how-to-solve-keyerror-unone-of-index-dtype-object-are-in-the-colum

o tambien es posible que se esten generando demasiadas columnas,

prueba a eliminar espacios y saltos de linea, y probar con menos columnas ....

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tenía pendiente agradecerlo. Saludos